# Server timeout/login error in PHP using mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql, iis, wampserver

I am new to PHP. I have worked a little before on it , but not much. Now, I have **IIS server** installed in my machine and it consumes **port 80** and for that reason I have changed the **wamp** server's port to **8080** in the config file.

Now ,what I have is a simple login form.The HTML markup looks like this :

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(isset($_REQUEST["error"])){
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Username and/or Password is incorrect!Please try again!");
    </script>        
<?php
    }
 ?>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="verifyUser.php">

<div class="container">
        <div class="card card-container">
            <!-- <img class="profile-img-card" src="//lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6V8xOA6M7BA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/rzlHcD0KYwo/photo.jpg?sz=120" alt="" /> -->
            <img id="profile-img" class="profile-img-card" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png" />
            <p id="profile-name" class="profile-name-card"></p>
            <form class="form-signin">
                <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>

                <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus><br>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

                <div id="remember" class="checkbox">

                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                    </label>

                </div>

                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Sign in</button>
            </form><!-- /form -->
            <a href="#" class="forgot-password">
                Forgot the password?
            </a>
            <br>

        </div><!-- /card-container -->
    </div><!-- /container -->

    </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and the PHP file, **`verifyUser.php`** looks like this :

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $pass = $_POST["password"];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","user",8080)  or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));

    $result_row = mysqli_query($con,"select * from info where Email='$email' and Password='$pass'");

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_row)){
        $_SESSION["existing_user"] = $row['Name'];
        $_SESSION["email"] = $row['Email'];
        header("location : home.php");
    }
    else{
        header("location:form1.php?error=1");
    }
?>
```

---

Now when I try to login, I get the error :

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\verifyUser.php on line 7

My error screen looks like this : 
[image]

I have studied this error and tried all the alternatives , which doesn't seem to work.One of them was to make some changes in **php.ini** file, but doesn't seem to work either!

Can someone tell me why is this ***actually*** happening and the ***solution*** for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to change port, the last argument is for Mysql port which is usually 3306, but 8080 is used by wamp which is totally diffrent from Mysql.

So this code should work just fine

```
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","user")  or die("Some error occurred during connection " . mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Oh god! Thank you so much! I mixed this up with wamp server's port.. Thank you again.. I will accept your answer in 7 minutes

Comment: Untill then, can you provide me good references to learn PHP from  ?except the official documentation page

Comment: I learned php from w3s, here is the link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp. It explains everything well with examples. Not perfect but best place to start!

Comment: I have started from there only! Anyways .. thank you once again!

Comment: If you had any problem in learning PHP just combine google with SO and that's all :D. Your welcome again.

Comment: `<i class="fa fa-user">Welcome, <?php echo "$_SESSION["existing_user"]"; ?> </i>` is this correct if I use this at home.php ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75659/discussion-between-abhishek-ghosh-and-black-hole).